# 2D Array item swap randomly

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I have an enum:

```
public enum Player
{
   X, O, NOBODY
}
```

And I have this array filled with player items randomly:

```
Player [size][size] p;
```

Example matrix:

```
[ X, NOBODY, NOBODY ]
[ NOBODY, O, O ]
[ X, X, NOBODY ]
```

I would like to swap an X or O element with a NOBODY element randomly, how can I do that?

Example:

```
[ NOBODY, NOBODY, NOBODY ]
[ NOBODY, O, O ]
[ X, X, X ]
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear.  You are expected to show us what you have tried and explain what you don't understand.  Also, what do you mean by "swap"?  Do you mean "find an existing X or O and change that one cell to NOBODY"? Or, do you mean "Find an existing X or O AND an existing NOBODY and exchange them"?

Comment: *FYI:* The `Player` type is an "enum", not an "enumerator". Enumerator sounds more like an [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html), which is the predecessor to the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: @JimGarrison By "swap", OP means exactly that. In the example, the upper-left corner (before: `X`, after: `NOBODY`) is swapped with the lower-right corner (before: `NOBODY`, after: `X`)

Comment: Find an existing X or O and an existing NOBODY and exchange them

Comment: Are you asking how to do something "random", or are you asking how to swap values, or what exactly is it you're asking? Please be *specific*.

Comment: I would like to select an x element randomly like the example and a i would like to exhange with a random NOBODY element.

Comment: Yes a have done research, but my solution was not that efficient.

Comment: @Beszteri For future reference, please include your code to try to narrow down exactly what your problem is.  Most users on this site love to see effort shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward approach would be to select a random X/O cell as well as a random NOBODY cell, and then swap their values:

```
// method inside class containing the array
public void swapValues() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int xoPos;
    int nobodyPos;

    do {
        xoPos = rand.nextInt(size*size);
        Player p = p[xoPos / size][xoPos % size];
    } while (Player.NOBODY.equals(p));

    do {
        nobodyPos = rand.nextInt(size*size);
        Player p = p[nobodyPos / size][nobodyPos % size];
    } while (!Player.NOBODY.equals(p));

    p[nobodyPos / size][nobodyPos % size] = p[xoPos / size][xoPos % size];
    p[xoPos / size][xoPos % size] = Player.NOBODY;
}
```

The strategy here is to generate a single random number between 0 and one minus the total number of cells in the 2D board.  Then, we use integer division and modulus to figure out to what 2D coordinates that single value corresponds.

Comment: Tim, have we begun to give free code to no-attempt questions?

Comment: @Andreas Interesting.  I was expecting some feedback, but what I was expecting was an anonymous downvote from Jim Garrison.  You have surprised me `:-)`

Comment: Tim, he probably hasn't seen it yet. But seriously, we shouldn't reward low quality questions like this, or the quantity of do-my-assignment-for-me questions will skyrocket. There are already way too many of them.